# How to permit any user (mysql, apache, etc) to use any TCP or UDP port?

Tags: networking, privileges

How can I ensure that all ports are open to any user?

Currently ports 1 to 1024 are reserved for "root" only.
Although I am not sure why "apache" is capable of using port "80" if this port too is reserved for "root".

I would like to simply free all ports so they can be used by any user.

Comment: Apache can use 80 because it runs as root initially, and then drops privileges. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation).

Comment: On Linux, the port≥1024 check is [built into the kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/vmw_vsock/af_vsock.c?v=3.16#L512) and cannot be modified or bypassed, only worked around (e.g. by arranging for all processes to have the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability).

Comment: Apache doesn't "drop" privileges.  It spawns children of generally a non root user.  The original Apache process is still running as root.  This allows for recovery operations.  If it dropped its privileges it would not be able to recover from networking errors and have to exit.  its also good to note that Linux capabilities cannot generally be applied to scripts.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this through Linux capabilities.  You'll need to set `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` and you can use the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user) as a guide.  However, as others have pointed out, this is an unwise thing to do.  Having a user take over port 22 or port 80 could have very bad consequences.

Comment: It also has the consequence of attackers knowing that 99% of the time, those ports are accessed by a root user.